# Детский вопрос о прилагательном «опушный»

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, тире, прилагательные

[А. И. Куприн. Конокрады](https://www.livelib.ru/book/136566/read-konokrady-aleksandr-kuprin):

> **Но Бузыга — он хитрый — он знает,** что если человеку после такого боя дать воды напиться, то тут ему и смерть. Справился он как-то и просит: «Православные хрестьяне, господа громада, как бы вы мне поднесли одну кляшечку горилки, а там хоть снова бейте. Чую я, что конец мой подходит, и мне хочется перед смертью в **опушный** раз попробовать вина». Те засмеялись, дали ему склянку.

• Некоторые особенные слова мы с ребенком "разобрали", а вот на прилагательном "опушный" споткнулись. Каково же его значение?

• Попутно (уже, собственно, мой интерес): смущает пунктуация в выделенном фрагменте. Правильна ли она?

Comment: Опушный как опушка - крайний. Ну и у Даля есть опушать - окаймлять , оторачивать.

Comment: Да, *мы* именно так, рассуждая логически, и предполагали — последний. Но ведь ни в одном словаре русского языка слова "опушный" нет, поэтому нет и его значения. Есть только *опушечный*. Спасибо огромное всем! P. S. "А мне так можно говорить?" Ответила — не стоит, не поймут.

Comment: Нужно говорить, а то чего вы зря слова учите что ли? Если учите, то так и нужно говорить, пользоваться и не стесняться, а то что не поймут - их проблемы. И я склоняюсь всё-таки к крайнему, а не к последнему - разные слова.

Comment: Последний - это скорее Куприн не совсем корректно употребил это слово, в переносном значении, близком, но не совсем точном. Либо из-за ассоциации с идиоматичным "в последний раз".

Answer (score 3):

> Некоторые особенные слова мы с ребенком "разобрали", а вот на прилагательном "опушный" споткнулись. Каково же его значение?

**ОПУШНЫЙ = последний.**

Из примечаний к сочинениям Куприна разных годов издания:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из русско-белорусского переводчика:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Рассказ «Конокрады» — не единственное произведение Куприна, в котором встречается слово ***опушный***. В конце 19-го века — за несколько лет до написания «Конокрадов»  — Куприн некоторое время провёл в Волынской губернии на северо-западе Украины, где работал управляющим поместьем, а затем в Полесье на юге Белоруссии. Впоследствии об этих местах Куприн писал: «Там я впитал свои самые сильные, благородные, обширные и плодотворные впечатления... и познакомился с русским языком и пейзажем», — вспоминал он.

На полесском материале Куприным был написан цикл рассказов, в том числе и рассказ «Лесная глушь» (1898). Встречается в этом рассказе Куприна и слово ***опушний***: *Вот пришло время и в поход выступать. Приехал Опанас в **опушний** раз на млын, прощается, бидака, со своей любой…*

> …Из всех произведений полесского цикла рассказ «Лесная глушь» наиболее густо насыщен местными словами и оборотами. Куприн был настолько пленён звучностью многих из этих местных слов, ему так хотелось точно передать колорит **местного полесского речения**. В байках Талимона есть слова, значение  которых нельзя понять, а поэтому в специальных сносках журнала «Русское богатство» давался перевод таких слов, как, например: «пыка — лицо», «ривчак — ручей», «става — пруд», «трапляется — случается», «охоче — когда», «завше  —  всегда», «опушный — последний», «хустка — платок». Таких слов в рассказе наберётся два-три десятка…

(Волков А.А. «Современники и предшественники. Литературные очерки». М., 1984.)

---

P.S. Пунктуация выделенного в вопросе фрагмента меня не смущает.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнительную информацию! *...колорит местного полесского речения.* Полесье, если я правильно помню, находится на территории **четырёх** современных государств (Белоруссия, Россия, Украина, Польша). Слово *опушный* (а теперь ещё и *опушний*) — девочка любознательна: так чьё же это слово?

Comment: В белорусском — _**апошни**_. В русском, украинском и польском слова, близкого по звучанию к приведённому в рассказе у Куприна со значением «последний», я не нашёл. Думаю, правы редакторы издания 1971 года, фрагмент из которого я привёл в своём ответе:  написание в книгах на русском _**опушный**_  (или _**опошний**_)  соответствует белорусскому произношению  «апошни».

Answer (score 2):

1. **О значении слова "опушный"**

В словаре есть глагол ***опушить*** — обшить **по краю** мехом. Также ***опушь*** это иконописный термин, полоса яркой краски **по краю** иконы. Тогда **"опушный"** имеет значение крайний, последний.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

Как мне думается, это **русское** слово. Сам **[Куприн](https://hthttps://greylib.align.ru/741/aleksandr-kuprin-tatarskie-korni.htmltps://)** родственных связей в Беларуси вроде бы не имел, но это надо уточнять.

2. **О пунктуации**

**По современным** правилам текст можно записать так:

*Главное, Бузыга — он хитрый на голову. О-го-го! Это такой человек! ... **Но Бузыга — он хитрый! — он знает,** что если человеку после такого боя дать воды напиться, то тут ему и смерть.*

**Пояснение**

Вставка смещена **к первой части,** но в авторском тексте это **не обозначено**. Два тире по правилам ставится в том случае, если на месте вставки **не было знаков.** Но здесь без вставки текст выглядит так: ***Но Бузыга** — он знает...*

Первая часть — **именительный** темы, нужна запятая или тире. Вместо запятой можно поставить **восклицательный** знак (подходит по тексту).

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**ОПУШИТЬ**, -св. кого-что. 1. Покрыть или окружить пушком, волосками или пушистой шерстью. Лапы зайца-беляка густо опушены. Листья рябины слабо опушены. Глаза, опушённые длинными ресницами. 2. Покрыть собой (о чём-л. лёгком, пушистом). 3. обычно страд. прич. прош. **Обшить по краям мехом**. Пальто, опушённое понизу дорогим мехом. Хочу о. капюшон и манжеты куницей. Опушать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Опушаться, -ается; страд. Опушка (см. 1.О.).

**[Опушь](https://www.culture.ru/s/slovo-dnya/opush/)**— это иконописный термин. Так называется **полоса яркой краски,** которая обрамляет икону по внешнему краю. Термин происходит от слова **«опушить», или «оторочить»** — то есть заметно выделить **край изделия**. Например, **в швейном деле** опушью называется **меховая обшивка по краю шапки** или рукавов, а «опушенными» в старину назывались лавки с резным навесом **по краю.**

Answer (score 1):

Ответу Славы и от меня тоже плюс.
В качестве дополнения привожу (свои) соображения – почему опушный = последний.

По Далю, одно из значений слова «опушка» - краешек, край.
...Опушка, пушистый край, кромка, кайма, обложка, оторочка, обшивка. Шубка, с собольей опушечкой. Бархатная опушка. Идти опушкой леса, краями, кустарниками, по обраменью...
Толковый словарь Даля. В.И. Даль. 1863-1866.

В русском языке широко используется сочетания «крайний случай», «крайняя мера» в значении «последний вариант / способ». Говорят и «крайний раз», правда очень редко. Летчики, к примеру, не любят слова «последний».
Все летаем на Благовещенск. Крайний раз был рейс наслаждений. Погода звенела, Муйские хребты были великолепны... [В. В. Ершов. Дневник (1988) // Летные дневники. 1984-2002 годы / Проза.ru]
Можно предполагать, что соответствие значений «опушка» = «край» вполне объясняет, почему в белорусском «апошнi» означает «последний».
Сочетание «в последний раз», как правило, запятыми не выделяют.
А если судьба спросит, куда я хочу перед смертью в последний раз сплавать, знаете, что я у нее попрошу? [Виктор Конецкий. Начало конца комедии (1978)]

Comment: А откуда Куприн взял это слово?  У него ряд таких слов. Местное наречие, диалект?  Почему в обычных словарях оно не обозначено?

Comment: Сведения из Вики: В 1894 году поручик Куприн вышел в отставку и переехал в Киев, не имея никакой гражданской профессии и решив посвятить себя литературному труду. 
«Оле́ся» — одно из первых крупных произведений Куприна написано в 1898-99 годах, и в 1899 году опубликовано в газете «Киевлянин». 
Героя повести - Ивана Тимофеевича судьба забросила «на целых шесть месяцев в глухую деревушку Волынской губернии, на окраину Полесья.

Comment: Спасибо! А вы не знаете, что там за диалект. Есть ли у нас хорошие диалектные словари?  Поискала в Интернете, но не нашла.